# Works on emulator but not on device. Finding error

Tags: android, radio-button

It works perfectly in emulator, but on device it crashes every time when RadioButton is pressed, so it must be some error in part of code after RadioButton, but I cannot find it.

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {


        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

        final EditText min_odds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.min_odds);

        final EditText probability_home = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.probability_home);
        final EditText probability_draw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.probability_draw);
        final EditText probability_away = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.probability_away);   

        double verjetnost = 0;
        final double koeficient;

        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.homewin:
                if (checked)                 

                    verjetnost= Double.valueOf(probability_home.getText().toString());
                    koeficient = 1/verjetnost*100;
                    min_odds.setText(String.valueOf((df.format(koeficient))));
                break;
            case R.id.drawdraw:
                if (checked)             

                    verjetnost= Double.valueOf(probability_draw.getText().toString());
                    koeficient = 1/verjetnost*100;
                    min_odds.setText(String.valueOf((df.format(koeficient))));
                break;
            case R.id.awaywin:
                if (checked)

                    verjetnost= Double.valueOf(probability_away.getText().toString());
                    koeficient = 1/verjetnost*100;
                    min_odds.setText(String.valueOf((df.format(koeficient))));
                break;

        }
```

I get this error on Logcat when pressing RadioButton:

```
    02-02 05:37:18.265: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.265: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.275: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.275: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.275: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.275: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
   02-02 05:37:18.275: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
   02-02 05:37:18.275: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
   02-02 05:37:18.275: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
   02-02 05:37:18.275: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.355: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.355: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.375: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.375: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.385: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.405: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.435: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.455: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.495: E/SoundPool(372): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.495: W/AudioService(372): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    02-02 05:37:18.495: W/AudioService(372): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
```

I have the same errors like that in previous two activitites but app doesn't crashes, so that's not the problem. But I don't have any other errors or exceptions in LogCat.

Any other ways to find an error?

Comment: There is a app called LogCollector. Install, run your application and when it crashes - retrieve the log.

Comment: Logcat added, I don't understand why Soundpool error?

Comment: you most probably have some Exception in your logcat...

Comment: It seems that it **can't find the ogg media files** you're trying to load. What I would try is to **COPY my sounds** into the **assets** or the **res/raw** folder and load them from there.

Comment: I found out that I have same errors like that in previous two activitites but app doesn't crashes, so that's not the problem. 
But I don't have any other errors or exceptions in LogCat, I don't get it.

Comment: The app doesn't crash, because, probably, there's an error trapping (i.e.: try...catch) surrounding the problematic lines. You see: it says it explicitly: **could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/xyz.ogg** in the method: **onLoadSoundEffects()**. So, you have those files on your emulator, but not on your devices. It can easily be due to **different versions** of the OS or you installed a **custom rom** on your device.

Comment: And how would I include those files in app so they would be on all devices?